# ryo-modal defining keybind jump a word and insert character

Tags: text-editing

I'm using the `ryo-modal` package that enables you to define your own keys in modal editing. I'm trying to makem`f` move the cursor to the end of the word, insert a whitespace and then exit the modal mode. This works fine without the `:then '(insert " ")` part. However, I would really like to see my original idea working. Thanks in advance.

```
(ryo-modal-key "f" 'forward-word :then '(insert " ") :exit t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`(ryo-modal-key "f" 'forward-word :then (list (lambda () (interactive) (insert " "))) :exit t)`

Comment: @stefan Actually you don't need to make it interactive, and having a quoted list works as well. That being said, your edited answer works too (but isn't as compact). I'm the author of `ryo-modal` and the non-interactive lambda feature was added because I thought the code looked cluttered when writing `interactive` everywhere :)

Comment: Then I suggest you change `ryo-modal-key`'s docstring because it says "list of additional commands" and a non-interactive function is not a command (whereas a string is a command, as is a vector of commands).  By the way I salso see you have `(if (commandp f) (call-interactively f) ...)` which should likely be replaced with `(if (commandp f) (command-execute f) ...)` since `call-interactively` doesn't know how to execute commands that are strings or vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions @stefan. I'll look into `command-execute` (and how it is different to `call-interactively`) and I agree that the docstring should change. I actually didn't realize that `(commandp "a")` would be `t`, even though I knew strings could be used as commands.